# Highcharts - Toggle bar chart direction (Horizontal/Vertical)

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am currently using Highcharts version 11.2.0 along with the official Angular wrapper highcharts-angular version 4.0.0. My goal is to toggle the direction of a bar chart (H/V). Changing it from vertical (V) to horizontal (H) is successful, but the reverse operation is not functioning as expected. I have identified this as a potential issue, possibly an ongoing bug (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5853). I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this matter.

The provided code initializes the chart as a column chart, and upon clicking a button, it invokes the changeBarDirection() function with the argument set to 'bar'. This successfully switches the chart direction from vertical to horizontal. However, the reverse operation does not yield the expected results.

My HTML

```
    <highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  [(update)]="updateFlag"
  (chartInstance)="logChartInstance($event)"
  style="display: block; height: 86%; background-color: var(--surface-card)"
  class="border-round-3xl"
></highcharts-chart>
```

TS File

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss'],
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() barDirection = 'column';

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {};
  chartInstance: Highcharts.Chart | undefined;
  updateFlag: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: this.barDirection,
      },
      title: {
        text: undefined,
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          'Ford Kuga',
          'Abu SULAIMAN',
          'Markov PM',
          'ISIS',
          'Hamass',
          'RASD',
          'Seat Ibiza',
          'Abu Jihad',
          'Taliban',
          'Tindouf',
        ],
        title: {
          text: null,
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 0,
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Link Deep',
          align: 'high',
          style: {
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
            fontFamily: 'EB Garamond',
          },
        },
        labels: {
          overflow: 'justify',
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions',
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        },
        column: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      series: [
        {
          type: this.barDirection,
          data: [75, 15, 63, 90, 75, 15, 63, 90, 55, 61],
        } as any,
      ],
    };
  }

  logChartInstance(chart: Highcharts.Chart) {
    this.chartInstance = chart;
  }

  changeBarDirection(selectedDirection: string) {
    this.barDirection = selectedDirection;
    if (this.chartInstance) {
      this.chartInstance.update(
        {
          chart: {
            inverted: true
          },
        },true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This question has also been raised in our Highcharts forum; therefore, the discussion will continue there:  https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=51798